# CSS3 sprite animation for different size

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm trying to do css3 animation with sprite sheet for different sizes. Full image size is working fine but it's not working as expected for other sizes(in my case half of the image size). It's shifting.

Here is working code with actual image size

```
/* ----button------ */
.button {
    width: 491px;
    height: 451px;
    background: url("http://i.imgur.com/vzEZHwu.png");
    background-size: auto 100%;


}
.button:hover{
       animation: play 3s steps(10) infinite;
  }

@keyframes play {
   from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -4960px; }
}
```

So, now i tried with half of the image size(4960/2= 2480) with below code
(not only half of the image size, need different size. I tried half of the image size)

```
/* button1 */
.button1 {
    width: 250px;
    height: 225px;
    background: url("http://i.imgur.com/vzEZHwu.png");
    /* background-size: 2480px auto; */ ---this one works 
    background-size: auto 100%; ----here is the problem, image is shifting


}
.button1:hover{
       animation: play1 3s steps(10) infinite;
  }

@keyframes play1 {
   from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -2480px; }
}
```

Also, can I use everything as percentage value so that it will work as responsive. I tried `background-position: -4960px;` into `background-position: 100% 0;` but unsuccessful.

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4g551yed/5/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work. Completely responsive:

```css
.button {
    width: 25%;
    background: url("http://i.imgur.com/vzEZHwu.png");
    background-size: 1000% auto;
}
.button:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    padding-top: 90%;
}
.button:hover{
       animation: play 3s steps(10) infinite;
  }

@keyframes play {
   from { background-position:     0% 0; }
     to { background-position: -1000% 0; }
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
    <a href="#" class="spriteBtn" ></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey Thomas, nice. I will implement this logic. but can you please explain how did you use 1000%? What i understood is 10 images in sprite sheet so 10*100. is that right?  Also why do we need `:before` here? Sorry if that was silly question. I'm new to UI.

Comment: You are right with the 1000%. The :before is needed to keep the aspect ratio of 1:0.9 of the responsive Button.

Comment: @LearneRツ if the answer correct, please also mark it as correct, so it is easy for other users to see if the problem got solved :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Duplicate your image and half the size.
2. Remove background-size from the button1 class.

HTML:

```
<div class="button">
    <a href="#" class="spriteBtn" ></a>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="button1">
    <a href="#" class="spriteBtn2" ></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* ----button------ */
.button {
    width: 491px;
    height: 451px;
    background: url("http://i.imgur.com/vzEZHwu.png");
    background-size: auto 100%;


}
.button:hover{
       animation: play 3s steps(10) infinite;
  }

@keyframes play {
   from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -4960px; }
}
/* button1 */
.button1 {
    width: 250px;
    height: 225px;
    background: url("http://s21.postimg.org/66xjk6391/vz_EZHwu.png");
    /* background-size: 2480px auto; */


}
.button1:hover{
       animation: play1 3s steps(10) infinite;
  }

@keyframes play1 {
   from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -2480px; }
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4g551yed/6/)

Comment: Hi i am trying to do without re sizing an image.  Is that possible?

Comment: What's wrong with using the working method "background-size: 2480px auto;" instead of "background-size: auto 100%;".

Comment: It should be responsive